# How to read only a specific part from HTTP Response body in c#?

Tags: c#, http, request, httprequest, httpresponse

I need only the "points": 300 from the below response body.

**Here is the body:**

```
{
  "channel": "abcd",
  "username": "fgh",
  "points": 300,
  "pointsAlltime": 0,
  "watchtime": 0,
  "rank": 1
}
```

**The Code:**

```
public async int get_points(string user){
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage
 {
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new 
    Uri("https://api.streamelements.com/kappa/v2/points/abcd/fgh"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "Accept", "application/json" },
        { "Authorization", "Bearer 123" },
    },
  };
 using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
 {
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
 }
}
```

I need only the points value. - 300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deserialize your string response into JSON and with the help of the property name you need to extract the `points` value.

Using [`JObject.Parse(String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm),

```
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(result);
    Console.WriteLine(jObj["points"]);
}
```

You can also try the native .NET approach introduced in .NET 6+ versions i.e. [`JsonNode.Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.parse?view=net-7.0#definition),

```
var jNode = JsonNode.Parse(result);
Console.WriteLine(jNode["points"]);
```